# How can sed output be formatted like printf's formatted printing?

Tags: text-processing, sed, columns

Can sed replace text with a string formatted like printf's formatted printing?

The following sed command replaces a line starting with the current value of "$domain" with several values specified in variables.

```
/bin/sed  "s/\(^${domain} *${limittype} * ${limititem}.*\)/$EXPL#\1\n${domain} ${limittype} ${limititem} ${value}/" /etc/security/limits.conf
```

However the output will not be properly aligned because the length of the values of domain etc. are not the same.

So the output would be something like

```
#oracle   hard   nproc    131072
oracle hard nproc 666
```

While valid, it is difficult to read.  I would prefer to get something like

```
#oracle   hard   nproc    131072
oracle   hard   nproc    666
```

The best I can come with to get the desired output is:

```
/bin/sed  "s/\(^${domain}\)\( *\)\(${limittype}\)\( *\)\(${limititem}\)\( *\)\(.*\)/$EXPL#\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\n${domain}\2${limittype}\4${limititem}\6${value}/" /etc/security/limits.conf
```

But I believe there must a more elegant way to do this.

The [sed one liners document](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt) contains some examples that use a specified number of characters, e.g.

```
sed -e :a -e 's/^.\{1,78\}$/ &/;ta'  # set at 78 plus 1 space
```

But this is in the `regexp` section not in the `replacement` section.

Comment: use tabs instead of spaces in the replacement?

Comment: Can you please provide an example input section and its corresponding preferred output?  Your `$EXPL#\1\n` bit seems wrong.

Comment: No.  `sed` can't do this in any way that is practical.  If you can provide a clearer description of the problem, many people here can provide an alternative solution using `bash`, `awk`, or any number of other tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This uses the extended regex syntax `-r`, which clears up a lot of the clutter. Also, because you already know some of the field values, you don't actually need to back-reference them, again reducing clutter (and overhead).

`&` is a special replacement value: it hold the entire matched pattern. Using the `&`, again reduces clutter. As it is not a back-reference, it has significantly less overhead.

I've used `( +)` vs. `( *)`. The `+` assumes that there is at least one space between input fields. Just change it to the `*` it that is not the case.

```
EXPL=
dom=oracle
typ=hard
itm=nproc
val=666

echo "oracle   hard   nproc    131072" |
  sed -r "s/^$dom( +)$typ( +)$itm( +).*/$EXPL#&\n$dom\1$typ\2$itm\3$val/"
```

output

```
#oracle   hard   nproc    131072
oracle   hard   nproc    666
```

Comment: Great! Does exactly what I want and thanks for the explanation on `&`.

Answer (score 6):

While you can theoretically do this entirely in sed (since it's Turing-complete), this isn't the right tool for the job.

An easy way is to insert tabs in sed, then post-process them to spaces. If you can determine the position of all columns, pipe the sed output through [`expand`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/expand.html).

```
</etc/security/limits.conf \
sed  "s/\(^${domain} *${limittype} * ${limititem}.*\)/$EXPL#\1\n${domain}\t${limittype}\t${limititem}\t${value}/" |
expand -t 10,17,26
```

(Use a literal tab character instead of `\t` if your sed doesn't support `\t`.)

If you don't know the column widths in advance, try the BSD [`column`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=column&sektion=1) utility. It looks at the whole input file to determine column widths that accommodate the length of all rows.

```
</etc/security/limits.conf \
sed  "s/\(^${domain} *${limittype} * ${limititem}.*\)/$EXPL#\1 ${domain} ${limittype} ${limititem} ${value}/" |
column -t
```

If your sed script rewrites both commented-out lines and non-commented-out lines, or if you use `column`, you'll need a bit of post-processing to skew the commented-out lines by the width of the comment marker.

```
… | sed '/^#/ s/ //'
```

You can use awk instead. It has a `printf` function. As an added bonus, there is an easy way to protect special characters such as `.` or `*` in a searched-for column content.

```
</etc/security/limits.conf awk -v domain="$domain" -v limittype="$limittype" -v limititem="$limititem" -v value="$value" '
$1 == domain && $2 == limittype && $3 == limititem  {
    printf "#%-9s %-8s %-9s %s\n%-9s %-8s %-9s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $1, $2, $3, value; next
}
1 {print}
'
```

Comment: Or possibly `column -t`.

Comment: I'll play with the awk version a bit, just as an excercise but right now I can't get it to work.  Thanks for the elaborate answer!

Comment: @Mikel Oh, thanks for remininding me. I meant to say “expand if you know the width, column if you don't” and forgot to write a paragraph.

Comment: @Bram I missed out a bit in the awk snippet to print out the input if it doesn't match, try now.

Comment: @Gilles: I edited the answer, removing the check on value because `$value` contains the new value and the proposed version would never match a line.  I also added an extra line of input so a comment would be written showing the old value.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Just use printf to format sed output:

```
printf "%5s %12s %4s\n" $(sed 's/.../.../')
```

Comment: I've seen people embed printf into sed, like `sed 's/xxx/$(printf "%5s %12s %4s\n")yyy/'` but is it doing a sub-process for each line processed? If so then doing the OPs problem in awk, using it's printf feature probably makes more sense. Good luck to all